# Upgrading GNU Awk on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

I would like to upgrade GNU Awk version 3.1.8 to the latest version. How can I upgrade versions using Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than compiling from source as in the answer of @maggotbrain, and totally confuse your package management, use a newer package instead.

Download the one for Quantal [here (4.0.1)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gawk) and install using for example

```
sudo dpkg -i gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
```

It has very standard dependencies easily met in Ubuntu Precise, so this is a very trivial backport.

Advantages:

- You don't overwrite files managed by your package management
- Reverting is also very easy by just telling your package management to install another candidate version.
- Does not involve compiling and therefore
- does not require you to install the build dependencies.

However, don't just blindly upgrade software on your system. Keeping older, stable versions is part of the release schedule of Ubuntu. This makes sure developers can 'freeze' the shared libraries and use them efficiently. Security and severe bugs will be backported to the versions as released with the OS release.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a more recent (untested against Ubuntu) version, you can download the latest tarball from the source at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tag/?id=gawk-4.0.1 and run the commands:

```
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```

I would also recommend reading the Ubuntu [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) prior to installing just to make sure you have the necessary tools on your system already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run the command  "make install" I got the following error.cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/_inst.7856_': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2.
How to solve this error?

Comment: @jameela try the command `sudo make install`

Comment: Don't do this! This will overwrite the version of gawk installed by your package with your custom compiled one. Now Ubuntu's record of what package is installed won't match the actual files on your system, and it'll get very confused. If you really want to compile your own version, look into the `--prefix` option to configure to allow you to install the two versions side by side.